# Objective-C multiple method warning

Tags: objective-c

I'm getting a warning in the following method:

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
 setObjectValue:(id)anObject
 forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn
            row:(int)rowIndex
{
    NSString *identifier = [aTableColumn identifier];
    Person *person = [employees objectAtIndex:rowIndex];

    NSUndoManager *undo = [self undoManager];
    [[undo prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] tableView:aTableView setObjectValue:[person valueForKey:identifier] forTableColumn:aTableColumn row:rowIndex];
    if(![undo isUndoing])
    {
        [undo setActionName:@"Edit Person"];
    }
    [person setValue:anObject forKey:identifier];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

I'm trying to implement undo so I figure I would call the same method and just pass the old value.  The error I'm getting is "warning: multiple methods named '-tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row:' found".  Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method on NSTableViewDataSource is declared as:

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView setObjectValue:(id)anObject forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
```

Your method uses `int` as the type of the `rowIndex` variable.   Change that to `NSInteger` and all will be fine.

The underlying issue is that Objective-C does not support co-variance or contra-variance in method argumentation, leading to the warning.

---

Note also that you are colluding data model with view layer.   Undo in this fashion is going to be very very tricky;  if you don't also manage the undo stack in the context of every sort of the table and/or addition/removal of rows, undo is going to apply the value to the wrong row.

You would be far better off reworking your app such that you have a proper separation of model view and controller.

Comment: The solved the problem.  It's a small example app.  I suppose normally if I were doing this, I would have a separate controller class (I'm not using NSController or bindings) but how would doing that prevent me from having to manage the undo stack?  Don't I have to manage the undo stack everytime I add/delete/edit something anyway?

Comment: It won't prevent you from managing the undo stack, but it'll move undo stack management largely into the data/controller layer, which will be significantly less fragile.  Better yet, you should be able to leverage the various controllers built into Cocoa to make all of this significantly easier and more flexible (or, even, Core Data -- I use Core Data for dead simple apps simply because it eliminates almost all code).

Comment: My understanding is that only Mac OS support things like NSController and bindings and that if you're programming legacy stuff/iOS you don't have those classes to work with.  I understand that they're useful but if I can't use them I'd like to know other things.

Comment: Bindings are Cocoa only.  iOS has lots of different controllers, though.  See http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller as an example.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's what got rid of the warning:

```
[((MyDocument *)[undo prepareWithInvocationTarget:self]) tableView:aTableView setObjectValue:[person valueForKey:identifier] forTableColumn:aTableColumn row:rowIndex];
```

Casting to the class that I was in cleared up the ambiguity I suppose.